# How to know if the video is in fullscreen in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, fullscreen

I tested the JavaScript code below to detect if the HTML5 video is in full screen or not. The code worked perfect in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but not in IE. How do I get this working in Internet Explorer? I tried "document.msFullscreenElement" but that didn't work.

```
if( document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement ||     document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement || document.oFullscreenElement)
   mode = "FULLSCREENVIDEO";
 else
   mode = "REGULAR";
```

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?